# C# interface operation name

Tags: c#, interface

What the official name of this operation in programming scient?
Boxing or what?
I mark the line with "<----"

```
        Auto a = new Auto();

        // What de name of this operation? boxing or... ?
        INitro inintro = a; // <--- There
        inintro.DoExecute();

class Auto:INitro,IChip
{

    void INitro.DoExecute()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("INITRO");
    }

    void IChip.DoExecute()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("ICHIP");
    }
}
interface INitro
{
    void DoExecute();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean “assignment”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an "upcast".

Imagine inheritance hierarchy as going top-to-bottom from least derived to most derived types. What you are doing in the example above is treating more derived type as a less derived type. You are effectively going "up" through the inheritance hieararchy - hence **up** cast.

You can do that since more derived type is guaranteed to have everything the less derived has (but not the other way around).

---

BTW, you re not changing the type of the object, you are just making another reference to it, and that reference happens to restrict you only to less derived "portion" of the object.

This is the basis of polymorphism. When you call `inintro.DoExecute()` in the line below, it will do so through so called "dynamic dispatch" (not to be confused with [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type) and pick the method based on the run-time type of the object. This is not particularly useful in this case, since you could just `a.DoExecute()`, but is one of the fundamental techniques for organizing big programs, where run-time type of a specific object may not be known in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's not boxing or unboxing.It's `Polymorphism` :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's polymorphism probably only in the line below that, when the `DoExecute` method is actually invoked. (If the C# compiler didn't typecheck there and allowed the assignment of incompatible types, which would then fail at runtime, it wouldn't be called "polymorphism", either, after all.)